# Kubernetes GKE: pods running, but ingress still says "unhealthy"; using TCP liveness/readiness, ssl port 443 but ingress reports 80?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

[image]I am continuing to try and get this GKE https loadbalancer up, but have one killer issue remaining: my pods look healthy (don't report any issue with 'describe pod') but the ingress still says UNHEALTHY ... also the service is on port 443 and the ingress continues to report port 80.

I am using TCP socket connections for liveness/readiness probes since that's what the application is set up to do. It's a TCP JSON-returning thing, not an HTTP protocol.

UPDATE: I added a second container to the pod with NGINX and moved the liveness/readiness probes there: no difference.

Here's all the deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: cleardev-deployment
  labels:
    app: clearspring
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: clearspring
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: clearspring
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: clearspring
        image: gcr.io/clearspring-dev/cleardev2:49477e1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        readinessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 8080
          successThreshold: 1
          failureThreshold: 5
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 10
        livenessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 8080
          successThreshold: 1
          failureThreshold: 5
          initialDelaySeconds: 15
          periodSeconds: 20
```

And the service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: clearspring-service443
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: clearspring
  ports:
    - name: https
      protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 8080
```

the cert:

```
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1
kind: ManagedCertificate
metadata:
  name: clearspring-cert
spec:
  domains:
    - api.clearspringinsurance.com
```

And the ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: clearspring-ingress
  annotations:
    # If the class annotation is not specified it defaults to "gce".
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "kubething"
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: clearspring-cert
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: clearspring-service443
      port:
        name: https
```

One workaround that occurs to me is to add a second container to the pod, like nginx, that will return the http 200 response without problem.

Any other ideas? Thanks much for any suggestions whatsoever!

Comment: If I understand correctly, your app itself does not support HTTP/HTTPS?  It's a TCP socket-based app and you are trying to terminate TLS outside the app?

Comment: On the healthcheck, the HTTP(S) load balancer only support HTTP/HTTPS/HTTP2 protocols for healthchecks.

Comment: Re-check Your ingress configuration rules , refer to [similar fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56187391/how-do-i-make-an-ingress-forward-to-an-ssl-port443-if-https-traffic) and solutions in stackoverflow. Share an error message if your issue is still not resolved.

Comment: Gari Singh: yes, it's a TCP socket based app. The documentation says that a TCP connection health check is available and in fact that does seem to work. But still the ingress is marked "UNHEALTHY". I tried a separate HTTP container in the same pod and moved the readiness and liveness probes there and made them httpGet ... but still it doesn't work. Same thing: pods running and look ok but UNHEALTHY ingress.

Comment: Ramesh: I just see a warning about "insufficient quota to handle this request" and found a note that sometimes has to do with insufficient IPs so trying in a different region to see if that helps ... in any event this should be an ERROR or a CRITICAL fault and not just a warning, IMHO ...

Comment: I tried another cluster in us-west1-b and it showed up UNHEALTHY after about an hour just like the other ones in us-central ... I just see a few warnings and am attaching a screenshot ..

Comment: The problem is not associated with IP Address availability, It’s about allowing traffic on port 443 for Ingress.Kindly check if you can [add appropriate rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56187391/how-do-i-make-an-ingress-forward-to-an-ssl-port443-if-https-traffic) in ingress.

Comment: What's wrong with the rules I have? name = https should be equivalent to port = 443, right?

Comment: I think your service is not passing ingress health-check. Common issue here are firewall rules. Could monitor network inside your container? If not possible you can do it on the host machine. To check if there are any connections from GCP health check ip ranges - 130.211.0.0/22, 35.191.0.0/16.

Comment: I just turned off the firewall rules on the cluster I'm using before doing the deploy/service/ingress ... still UNHEALTHY ... does it take a while to become HEALTHY and if so how long?

Comment: Re-enabling the default Google compute Engine Service Account will resolve the insufficient quota issue . Adding annotation in kubernetes service definition and adding ‘servicePort: use-annotation’ in ingress spec can fix the issue of ingress reporting to port 80.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were several issues, but the basic one was liveness/readiness probes.

As far as I can tell, they *do not* support TCP connections, despite the documentation saying that they do.

The good news for my project is that it's based on Flask, which is http after all. So I just had to add a route '/healthz' to the Flask app (then fix it after I got 405 errors since I put it as *POST* and not *GET* the first time).

The other really weird thing was the syntax for getting the logs from the pods ... if you just give

```
kubectl logs -p  podname -n seven
```

you get an error "the previous pod doesn't exist".

If instead you add this flag:

```
kubectl logs -p  podname -n seven --previous=false
```

Then that shows the log I was looking for.

(Kubernetes geek who designed this: you owe me a cup of tea!)

Other nuances:

- the firewall setup on *kubernetes-minions-all* blocks too much so I just had to change it to 'allow all'
- static IPs don't get marked back to *RESERVED* when the cluster gets deleted but stay *IN USE* so if you just bring the cluster back up with that same static IP, the ingress fails ...

I think that's it ... *sheesh*!